# Why do the same height values look different in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I noticed this when I wanted to use a separator. They have the same height values but differ noticeably by eye. What is the reason for this and is there a solution?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
    
function App(){
      return(
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
    
          <View style={{ height: 2, width: "100%", marginVertical: 48, backgroundColor: "black" }} />
    
          <View style={{ height: 2, width: "100%", marginVertical: 48, backgroundColor: "black" }} />
    
        </View>
      )
}
    
export default App;
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Zoom to first line:

[image]

Zoom to second line:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code and showing perfectly on iPhone 13, maybe its issue is related to a specific device

[image: iPhone 13 Screenshot]

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <View style={{ height: 2, width: "100%", marginVertical: 48, backgroundColor: "black" }} />
      <View style={{ height: 2, width: "100%", marginVertical: 48, backgroundColor: "black" }} />
    </View>
  )
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I have experienced this situation many times on different Android devices. I don't know because I don't have an iOS device. It didn't catch my attention in the simulator. Maybe it works fine on iOS.